# How to find the underlying dynamical system given a probability distribution?

Tags: probability, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

From this [paper](https://pdodds.w3.uvm.edu/files/papers/others/1992/berliner1992a.pdf), I see one could use probability distribution to describe an ergodic system. For example, in page 12, consider logistic map $x_{t+1}=ax_{t}(1-x_{t})$ with $a=4$, its ergodic behavior can be described by a probability distribution $Beta(0.5, 0.5)$.

My question is: can we do the same thing in the opposite direction, i.e. find the underlying dynamical system given a probability distribution? If so, is the solution unique?

Thanks in advance!